# Simple string type variable comparison not working

Tags: autohotkey

I just want to compare two variables and check if they are equal. I have 2 commands for q and w that just set what the global lastCommand variable is. And for each command I want to do something if the lastCommand was a certain value but it doesn't seem to work. Is there something wrong with the way I'm trying to compare values in auto hot key?

```
#SingleInstance Force
CoordMode, Mouse, Client
CoordMode, Pixel, Client
SendMode Input
 
SetDefaultMouseSpeed, 0

global lastCommand := "q" 

q::
   if (lastCommand == "w") {
    Msgbox last command was w
   } else {
    Msgbox % lastCommand
   }
   lastCommand = "q"
   return 
w::
  if (lastCommand == "q") {
    Msgbox last command was q
  } else {
    Msgbox % lastCommand
   }
  lastcommand = "w"
  return
```

It's not complex...I just can't figure out why it's not working. The comparison for if ( lastCommand == "w") should trigger but it doesn't. The else blocks trigger and it still displays the value that should have caused the if statement to trigger.

Answer (score 3):

You're using legacy the legacy assign operator and assigning the literal string `"q"` (or `"w"`) to the variable `lastcommand`. As opposed to assigning the string `q` or `w`.

The fix? Never use the legacy assigning operator `=`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/SetEnv.htm)</sup>, use the modern expression assign operator instead `:=`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/SetExpression.htm)</sup>.